# VPN connections for mobile devices stopped working even though Sonicwall reports them as successful

Tags: vpn, l2tp, sonicwall

Suddenly, my wireless devices (a Samsung S9 and a 3rd generation Apple iPad Pro) no longer work with the VPN service that’s built into my corporate firewall, as they have for years. They both connect OK (near-instantly) and obtain a DHCP IP address from the firewall, but the connection is completely non-functional – if you try to load a web page in a browser, the progress bar goes to about 10% and then stops. You have to turn off VPN to restore functionality.

Meanwhile, the VPN connection continues to work perfectly with two Windows 10 desktops. Unlike the wireless units, the connection isn’t instant – there’s a 30-second “completing the connection” phase – but it always completes and gives me a working connection.

Especially confusing is that there are no errors in the log. Both Windows 10 and Samsung/iPad connections report the exact same connection data.

[image: Log records] [1](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/troubleshooting-l2tp-connectivity-when-using-iphone-ipod-ipad/170503714733725/): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeXNs.jpg

I’ve been through all the help for my VPN setup at [Troubleshooting L2TP connectivity when using iPhone, iPod, iPad | SonicWall](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/troubleshooting-l2tp-connectivity-when-using-iphone-ipod-ipad/170503714733725/). No luck.

Is there an obvious answer that a vpn-guru can provide? I can furnish any technical info you request.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem. The iPad and the Samsung Galaxy both use IKEv2 for the VPN connection -- my Sonicwall only supports IKEv1.